# NULL Objects in Received Playlists

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

Since recently, among the fetched playlist objects is a `NULL` object is contained in the resulting array. It looks like a nasty bug, as in the debugger a memory address is given, but no object type could be resolved. It crashes within Cocoalibspotify while iterating the array.

Someone else experiencing that issue?

Comment: Fetched from where? Fetched how? Please be more detailed and provide a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:

Among Spotify's Top Tracks, there is the song "Love Is All I Got - Original Mix". It's album does have a `nil` cover. As I'm creating the array with covers via the following line, for this track's cover, an `NSNull` object is inserted, which makes `cocoalibspotify` crash.

```
NSArray *covers = [toptracks valueForKeyPath:@"album.cover"];
```